# Getting data via Tradingview chart

Tags: javascript, python, c#

I'm trying to import data with selenium through trading view, but the table that appears in black does not appear in the HTML source code. I have searched with the texts in the table and cannot be found. It's probably like it's printed on the chart in image format, but when I look at it with a bookmark, it shows the whole chart. I couldn't find the Tag of this table.

Any ideas on how I can get this table?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiFyN.png)

I couldn't find an answer to my question and I decided to write it here. I think the answers will come.

Comment: It may be added by java code.

Comment: I think the question was misunderstood. I want to scrape the data of the table on the chart with selenium. But the table does not appear in HTML codes.

Comment: A webpage can have more than one view.  Views can be a URI to a different webpage.  Some views are added by java code.   The data you are looking for is in one of these views.  Sometimes you just have to wait to get the view data because java is still running when the HTML is first returned.

Comment: It's not about waiting. After the data is loaded, the HTML code is the same.

Comment: A view can be a separate URI